# Who and where is the cheapest dark magic character, in Lego Harry Potter 2?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

I'm playing the Wii version, and I don't own any dark magic characters, but I have unlocked some - they just cost too much.

I've got Voldemort (25,000,000 studs), Bellatrix Lestrange (3,750,000 studs) and Azkaban Bellatrix (3,750,000 studs).

I would like to know where the cheapest dark magic character is, without having to use a dark magic character to unlock them.

Answer (score 1):

You can unlock Tom Riddle in the final area of level 8-4 "Fiendfyre Frenzy" without needing to have a pre-existing dark magic character.

He costs 2,000,000 studs.